# Php - upload file with ajax

Tags: php, ajax

my 2form.php :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mootools.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function test()
    {
        url = '2form.php';
        var ajax = new Ajax(url, {
            method: 'post',
            onComplete: function(response) {            
                document.getElementById('error_upload_logo').innerHTML = response;
            }
        });     
        ajax.request();
    }   
</script>
<?php
    if($_FILES)
    {
        echo "<div>";
        foreach($_FILES['name'] as $v)
        {
            echo $v."<br/>";
        }
        echo "</div>";
    }
    else
    { ?>
        <form action='' id='form1' name="form1" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="name"/>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" onclick='test(); return false;'/>
        </form>
<?php
    }
?>

<div id="error_upload_logo"></div>
```

if run code with out javascript , it 2form.php like simple php page, and

we can see information of $_FILES that was printed to scrreen

But if i have run with javascript by test() function ,

i don't get information in $_FILES ?

How to get $_FILES ? when click button run with javascript ?

i want to upload with ajax

Answer (score 2):

You can't do file uploads using AJAX because you won't have access to the local file.

The most common workaround is what the [JQuery Form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) does, creating a temporary iframe and doing a normal form submit into it.

The other alternative is using a Flash-based uploader like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com).

Comment: what do u thik about something like this http://valums.com/ajax-upload/ , what sulotion was used ?

Comment: @Chameron it says on the front page `An older ajax upload plugin, which only used iframe for uploads...`

Comment: i viewed code , and see something like using js create a iframe with form upload , push pahtfile to input file and submit this form. I don't sure ? what do u think?

Comment: @Chameron yup, sounds like the way to go. However, the user must select the file in any case, you can't set the path programmatically.

Comment: @Chameron you can't, that is the whole point. You need to submit the form into the iframe to a normal PHP script. That script will have the $_FILES array available.

Comment: yeah . I think so. get $_FILES by ajax is impossible.  But I have to try to research it for my boss :))  . Thank you very much